# Cannot use import statement outside a module using Express and Typescript, I'm deeply confused about modules

Tags: node.js, typescript, express

I'm trying to learn Typescript but I've gotten hung up on using modules, imports and exports while using Express. First, my code (I'll shorten irrelevant parts):

**Full code**
https://github.com/coldblade2000/BannerServer

**courses.js ( "/courses route handler for Express)**

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const {CourseModel} = require('../MongoDB/models/models.ts')

const {Course} =  require('../model/Course.ts'); //<----ERROR HERE
//const {retrieveMultipleCourses} = require('../model/model.ts')

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/banner', {useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true});
/* GET users listing. */
router.get('/', async function (req, res, next) {
    ...
});

function isEmpty(obj) {
    ...
}

module.exports = router;
```

**Course.ts**

```
import * as mongoose from 'mongoose' //<----ERROR HERE: SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
// const mongoose = require('mongoose')
export interface Course{
    ...
}

export class CourseClass implements Course{
    ...
}


export interface Professor{
    ...
}
export interface Meeting {
    ...
}
export interface Days{
    ...
}
```

**Error**

```
> server@0.0.0 start C:\Users\diego\Desktop\BannerServer
> node bin/www.js && nodemon app.js

C:\Users\diego\Desktop\BannerServer\model\Course.ts:1
    import * as mongoose from 'mongoose'
    ^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
    at wrapSafe (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:979:16)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1027:27)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1092:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:928:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:769:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:952:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:88:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\diego\Desktop\BannerServer\routes\courses.js:6:19)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1063:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1092:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:928:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:769:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:952:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:88:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\diego\Desktop\BannerServer\app.js:9:21)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1063:30)
```

**Tsconfig.json**

````
```{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es6",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "rootDir": "./",
    "outDir": "./build",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "strict": true
  }
}
````

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "server",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "module": "CommonJS",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node bin/www.js && nodemon app.js",
    "build": "tsc --project ./",
    "tsc": "tsc",
    "dev": "nodemon —exec babel-node app.js"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@typegoose/typegoose": "^7.4.1",
    "@types/node": "^14.14.1",
    "cookie-parser": "~1.4.4",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "debug": "~2.6.9",
    "ejs": "~2.6.1",
    "express": "~4.16.1",
    "http-errors": "~1.6.3",
    "mongoose": "^5.10.4",
    "morgan": "~1.9.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.10",
    "@babel/node": "^7.12.10",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.12.11",
    "@types/mongoose": "^5.7.36",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.6",
    "ts-node": "^9.1.1",
    "typescript": "^4.1.3"
  }
}
```

So the problem I have is that I get `SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module` when I use `import * as mongoose from 'mongoose'` in Course.ts. I get the same error if I change `const Course =  require('../model/Course.ts');` in courses.js to `import Course from ''.../model/Course.ts'`, but this time in the line I just changed. Even when I try to change Course.ts to use module.exports, the problem persists. I am at my wits end, so I require help. Since Express doesn't seem to like ES6 modules, I don't think I can just put "type:module" in package.json. I put in

Comment: Share your tsconfig.json

Comment: @Evert There, I edited it in my post

Comment: The main idea with typescript is that you have a 'source' and a 'dest' directory. In your case it's 'build', `tsc` compiles everyhing, but when you run your code with `node`, you use only the code in your 'build' directory. Are you doing that?

Comment: You might also need the `allowJs` option if you are doing mixed javascript and typescript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix the issue. It was thanks to both @Hegazy and  @Evert.

My main issue, as @Evert pointed out, I changed my "start" script to first compile using tsc, and also pointed node to point to /build/... instead of just /....

My current **package.json**

```
{
  "name": "server",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "module": "CommonJS",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "tsc && node build/bin/www.js && nodemon app.js",
    "build": "tsc --project ./",
    "tsc": "tsc"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@typegoose/typegoose": "^7.4.1",
    "@types/node": "^14.14.1",
    "cookie-parser": "~1.4.4",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "debug": "~2.6.9",
    "ejs": "~2.6.1",
    "express": "~4.16.1",
    "http-errors": "~1.6.3",
    "mongoose": "^5.10.4",
    "morgan": "~1.9.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/mongoose": "^5.7.36",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^4.11.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^4.11.0",
    "eslint": "^7.16.0",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.6",
    "ts-node": "^9.1.1",
    "typescript": "^4.1.3"
  }
}
```

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es6",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "outDir": "./build",
    "declaration": true,
    "removeComments": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "allowJs": true,
    "incremental": true
  },
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "build"]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

TS file is not transpiled into JS in your build folder.
so to make sure go to the file bath in build folder and you will see it still *.ts file

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es6",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "outDir": "./build",
    "declaration": true,
    "removeComments": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "incremental": true
  },
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "build"]
}
```

Comment: I put that in, but the same problem persists. I think it might be a problem with my package.json script. I put it in my OP, mind checking it out?